# Android avd arrow keys not working

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am learning app development from a book, and have run into a problem with the avd. I have my code set up to change some text when the right arrow key is pressed:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT){
                textUpdate();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

When I run the virtual device and press the arrow keys nothing happens. When I press the arrow keys on my physical keyboard, still nothing. I have done a lot of research and can't find the solution. I have tried editing the avd settings and editing the device(Nexus One) itself to accept keyboard and dpad input. What should I try now?

Comment: did you enable your hardware keyboard in device setting?

Comment: If you mean by selecting hardware keyboard present and use host gpu then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, what happened was my onKeyDown() function was inside a Fragment. I don't know why, but when I moved this code into the mainActivity it worked fine. If anyone has an answer as to why this worked and how I could get it to work in the fragment please comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you overriden the method?
There should be an @Override above that function.

Override calls that function whenever its triggered so you can modify it to your specific implementation.

Hope this helps

Comment: When I add the @Override I get the error:"The method onKeyDown(int, keyEvent) of type mainactivity.placeholder fragment must implement or override a supertype method"

Answer (score 0):

the "arrow key" means the back key on android device? 
if it is then you should override the onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // do something 
}
```

Comment: No, I mean the right key on a dial pad. Up, down, left, right, center.

Comment: Same as the previous answer: onBackPressed must override or implement a supertype method.